# Swift debug: app stops at breakpoints and doesn't crash

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, swift, breakpoints

In the age of Objective C, when I had error in my code and run it I received green thread breakpoint, but if I push button "Continue program execution" in the Debug Area, my app crashes and shows me exact error description.

[image]

Right now I'm suffer from "breakpoint loop" which occurs if I push continue button it stops at the same place and never crash. App doesn't crash at all and I haven't got any app error description. This is really annoying me, `Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT, subcode=0xe7ffdefe)` isn't very useful information in point of view of good old fatal error descriptions and so on.

Is there a way to break this "breakpoint loop" and crash the app to see error description?

EDIT:

Note: here I used word breakpoint, I didn't  mean breakpoints that was set by myself, I meant default runtime crash breakpoints. Here is image of it (correct my if I named it wrong):
[image]

My breakpoint navigator:

[image]

Comment: Have you set an exception breakpoint? I find that even with Objective C an exception breakpoint can mask some exception messages.

Comment: @Paulw11, No, I haven't. Thanks for editing:)

Comment: Well, Afaik there are no default breakpoints - you should check the breakpoint navigator to make sure there is nothing there

Comment: @Paulw11 I added some images for explanation

Answer (score 5):

The EXC_BREAKPOINT exception just means that the program tried to execute some particular "trap" instruction.  That happens to be the instruction that debuggers use to set breakpoints.  However, there are a number of system components that also use the trap instruction to halt execution when the program hits some exceptional condition.  The idea being that if you are in the debugger, your app will stop and you can analyze the problem, but if not the app will die at that point.

You can tell whether the debugger is responsible for the trap because if lldb recognizes the EXC_BREAKPOINT as coming from a trap that it inserted, then it will tell you the stop reason was "breakpoint 1.1" or whatever - it won't show the raw EXC_BREAKPOINT as the stop reason.  So if you are seeing EXC_BREAKPOINT it means you got some kind of internal assertion failure.

Usually you can tell what's going on by going to the bottom-most frame in the stack and looking at the code that has the trap inserted in it.  Sometimes this isn't obvious in Xcode because if you stop for some exceptional reason in a stack where the bottom-most frames are assembly code, Xcode will select the lowest frame in the stack that has debug information.  But if you look at the stack, you may see more frames below the stack.

You will also sometimes see little chunks of code that belong to your function, but come after the normal return instruction for you function.  For instance, the stack guard mechanism will write a little error-handling section after some functions, and jump there and then trap if it notices stack overflow.